# do something if each class element has some value

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("#btn_02").click(function(){
    $(".quant").each(function() {
        var a = $(this).html();
        alert (a);  // each value is 0
        if (a == 0) {return false;}
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "process02.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#modalsCart").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to stop `ajax` code if each `.quant` value is `0`, and yes, they are all `0`, but `ajax` code is still executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... if all of the quants are 0, you want to not-execute the ajax call - right? You only want to execute the AJAX call if the amount of 'quants' is greater than 0.

What you could do to start with is keep track of the total `a` and then only execute the $.ajax call if `a` is > 0.

In **pseudocode** that would look something like this:

```
var totalA = 0;
$(".quant").each {
    totalA += a;
}
if (totalA > 0) {
    $.ajax(); // ajax call here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Notice you have 2 functions defined.  Your `return` inside the loop doesn't break out of the main one.  You need to set another variable in a scope visible to the lower function that you can check after you're done looping to decide whether or not to perform the ajax request.

```
$("#btn_02").click(function(){
    var hasA = false;
    $(".quant").each(function() {
        var a = $(this).html();
        alert (a);  // each value is 0
        if (a == 0) {hasA = true; return false;}
    });
    if (!hasA) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "process02.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#modalsCart").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```